# My javascript code isn't incrementing/decrementing in the if statement

Tags: javascript, html, forms, counter

I'm creating a form that will have multiple items to choose from and check in(add/increment) and checkout(minus/decrement)and it only works when the laptop variable is equal to 1. I want to set the total amount of an item and then whatever option they choose it'll either increment or decrement the variable associated with that item. I also can't figure out a way to make sure the variable won't reset every time the form closes and opens again.

```js
    function updateCount (form) {
     //need to figure out way for count to not reset to total when closing 
    form
     //only works when set to 1
     var laptop=1;
     if (form.option1.checked && form.optionin.checked) {
      laptop++;
      alert ("Your response has been recorded");
     }
     if (form.option1.checked && form.optionout.checked) {
      laptop--;
      alert ("Your response has been recorded"); 
     } 
     if (form.option1.checked && form.optionout.checked && laptop===0) {
      alert ("Item currently unavailable, choose another item");
     }}
```

```html
    <h1>CS Equipment Renatal Form</h1>
    <form>
     <!--top of form with name and line break for text, don't need 
    anything with the Name: -->
     Name:<br>
     <!--creating the variable type for textfield and the name of it which 
    is fullname-->
     <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
     <br>
     <!--email textfield with line break after meaning new line-->
     OU Email:<br>
     <input type="email" name="ouemail"><br>
     <br>
     <!--doing the checkboxes for rental types with id since the id is 
    used in the script -->
    Equipment Rental Type<br>
     Laptop <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="laptop" 
    id="option1"><br>
     Tablet <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="tablet" 
    id="option2"><br>
     Monitor <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="monitor" 
    id="option3"><br>
     Camera <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="camera" 
    id="option4"><br>
     <br>
     <!--doing checkboxes for checkout and check with id because its used 
    in script-->
     Select One<br>
 Check In <input type="checkbox" name="optionin" value="checkIn" 
    id="checkOut"><br>
     Check Out <input type="checkbox" name="optionout" value="checkOut" 
    id="checkIn"><br>
     <br>
     <!--adding submit button and associating it with script function-->
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" 
    onClick="updateCount(this.form)">

    </form>
```

Comment: Change button type to "button"

Comment: Are you new to web development? Because if this is your actual code and you want to keep track of the number of laptops checked out, you're going to need to learn server-side development as well, before you can build this. If you only need this to work on a single computer, and you don't need to access the data from any other computers, you could use local storage to store the number of laptops. Also, you will need to restructure your code, because using three `if` statements for each form option is be a bad and unmaintainable solution.

Comment: `form.option1` is not a valid way of accessing the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `var laptop=1;` should hold the number of available laptops.

The problem here is that you're declaring it inside the function that should actually manage it - so you're basically resetting it with each call to this function.

To get around this you need to make it a global variable - one whichs is defined before and outside of `function updateCount (form) { }`.

Furthermore you should get rid of the onclick event on the input field and instead use the onsubmit event on the form itself. This way you can validate the form before it's actually submitted.

Take a look at this example:

```js
var laptop = 1;

function updateCount(form) {

  if (form.option1.checked && form.optionin.checked) {
    laptop++;
    alert("Your response has been recorded");
    return true;
  }
  if (form.option1.checked && form.optionout.checked) {
    laptop--;
    alert("Your response has been recorded");
    return true;
  }
  if (form.option1.checked && form.optionout.checked && laptop === 0) {
    alert("Item currently unavailable, choose another item");
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<h1>CS Equipment Renatal Form</h1>
<form onsubmit="return updateCount(this)">
  <!--top of form with name and line break for text, don't need 
anything with the Name: -->
  Name:<br>
  <!--creating the variable type for textfield and the name of it which 
is fullname-->
  <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
  <br>
  <!--email textfield with line break after meaning new line-->
  OU Email:<br>
  <input type="email" name="ouemail"><br>
  <br>
  <!--doing the checkboxes for rental types with id since the id is 
used in the script -->
  Equipment Rental Type<br> Laptop <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="laptop" id="option1"><br> Tablet <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="tablet" id="option2"><br> Monitor <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="monitor" id="option3"><br>  Camera <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="camera" id="option4"><br>
  <br>
  <!--doing checkboxes for checkout and check with id because its used 
in script-->
  Select One<br> Check In <input type="checkbox" name="optionin" value="checkIn" id="checkOut"><br> Check Out <input type="checkbox" name="optionout" value="checkOut" id="checkIn"><br>
  <br>
  <!--adding submit button and associating it with script function-->
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: To expand on this answer, @mias, you really need to read up on the concept of a context in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Many issues here:

1- `form.option1` is not a valid way of accessing the checkbox with id `option1`. Use `document.getElementById("option1")` instead. Same goes for `optionin` and `optionout`

2- Your button has type "submit", which will reload the page and reset your variable `laptop` (unless you save it using a cookie or localStorage). A simple way of preventing the button from refreshing the page is changing its type to "button".

3- As pointed out by @obscure's answer, you should declare your variable `laptop` outside of the `updateCount` function.

4- I believe you don't want users to select both "Check in" and "Check out" at the same time. For this, use radio buttons instead of a checkbox (note that both radio buttons have the same `name` attribute, so that you can't select both together).

```js
var laptop=1; //will not reset as long as the page is not refreshed
//a way of preventing the from from refreshing the page is to change the button type to "button"

function updateCount (form) {
    var laptop = document.getElementById("option1");
    var option_in = document.getElementById("checkIn");
    var option_out = document.getElementById("checkOut");
    if (laptop.checked && option_in.checked) {
        laptop++;
        alert ("Your response has been recorded - Check In");
    }
    if (laptop.checked && option_out.checked) {
        laptop--;
        alert ("Your response has been recorded - Check Out"); 
    } 
    if (laptop.checked && option_out.checked && laptop===0) {
        alert ("Item currently unavailable, choose another item");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h1>CS Equipment Renatal Form</h1>
<form>
    <!--top of form with name and line break for text, don't need 
anything with the Name: -->
    Name:<br>
    <!--creating the variable type for textfield and the name of it which 
is fullname-->
    <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
    <br>
    <!--email textfield with line break after meaning new line-->
    OU Email:<br>
    <input type="email" name="ouemail"><br>
    <br>
    <!--doing the checkboxes for rental types with id since the id is 
used in the script -->
Equipment Rental Type<br>
    Laptop <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="laptop" 
id="option1"><br>
    Tablet <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="tablet" 
id="option2"><br>
    Monitor <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="monitor" 
id="option3"><br>
    Camera <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="camera" 
id="option4"><br>
    <br>
    <!--doing checkboxes for checkout and check with id because its used 
in script-->
    Select One<br>
Check In <input type="radio" name="changeQty" value="checkIn" 
id="checkIn"><br>
    Check Out <input type="radio" name="changeQty" value="checkOut" 
id="checkOut"><br>
    <br>
    <!--adding submit button and associating it with script function-->
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" 
onClick="updateCount(this.form)">

</form>
</html>
```

In order to save the `laptop` variable if the page is refreshed, consider using a cookie, localStorage, or some server-side scripting.